# Access test resources in REPL

Tags: scala, sbt, read-eval-print-loop

I find myself often using a REPL (`sbt console`), wishing that I had easy access to test resources. Specifically, this includes fixtures stored in `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/test/resources` and libraries in `$PROJECT_ROOT/src/test/scala`. Is there a way to start the REPL in some sort of "test mode" so it knows to include test resources in the classpath?

Comment: This question is a little different because it's asking about user resources and libraries, not 3rd party libraries. `sbt test:consoleQuick` does not include test sources. I should have made the distinction more clear. Nevertheless thank you, the [documentation](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Scala.html) linked from that answer contained the solution as well as other relevant, useful information: "To enter the REPL with test dependencies and compiled test sources on the classpath, run `test:console`"